# How can I make a list defined in one method available in another method when both methods are in the same class?

Tags: python, methods

I have `two methods within the same class`, and I want to make a `list` in one method available in the other method, how do I do this?

Here is my code:

```
class Solution:
    primes=[]

    def primeNumber(self,n):
        numbers = set(range(n, 1, -1))
        self.primes = []
        while numbers:
            p = numbers.pop()
            self.primes.append(p)
            numbers.difference_update(set(range(p * 2, n + 1, p)))

    def goodNumbers(self,f):
        self.primes.append(f)
        return self.primes

x=Solution()
print(x.primeNumber(100)) ##populate the list
print(x.goodNumbers(123456789)) ##return the list as populated by previous call, and with the long number appended
```

For some reason, self.primes does not take into account the long number appended in goodNumbers()- any idea why this is?

Comment: Any Python tutorial would cover this in the section on classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has already been said, you can use an *instance variable* `self.primes` instead of your *local variable* `primes`. This is useful if you plan to reuse the values.

If instead you simply want to use the values once, and you want `goodNumbers` to call `primeNumber`, then simply add `return primes` at the end of `primeNumber` (outside the `while` loop of course)

**EDIT**

Since the question has been modified:

I just saw your edited question. That won't work: if you're using `self.primes` for passing data between methods then you need to first *create* it, probably at object initialization time, then to *populate* it with a call to `primeNumber`, and then you can *read/modify* it in `goodNumbers`.

For example:

```
class Solution:
    primes=[]

    def primeNumber(self,n):
        numbers = set(range(n, 1, -1))
        self.primes = []
        while numbers:
            p = numbers.pop()
            self.primes.append(p)
            numbers.difference_update(set(range(p * 2, n + 1, p)))

    def goodNumbers(self,n):
        self.primes.append(7598347534)
        return self.primes

x=Solution
x.primeNumber(100) ##populate the list
x.goodNumbers(123456789) ##return the list as populated by previous call, and with the long number appended
```

Comment: Thanks gimix- one question, if I define self.primes say in the first method, would I have to return it in order to call it in another method? Otherwise, how can I use self.primes in another method?

Comment: `self.primes` is an attribute of the object, and is directly available to every method (and outside the object as well: if your instance of `Solution` is called `x` then `x.primes` gives you the list). So once `primeNumber` writes `self.primes` then you simply access it in `goodNumbers` or any other methods as `self.primes`

Comment: Thanks Gimix, one last time please- I have edited the question. Why does the x.primeNumber(100) return None? But x.goodNumbers(123456789) works just fine, it prints a list of primes up to 100, and then appends 123456789.

Comment: Sorry, I missed out the parenthesis, it's `x=Solution()` as you say. It doesn't print anything, because you no longer have a `print()` call - it _returns_ the list: try `y = x.goodNumbers(123456789)`, or just `print(x.goodNumbers(123456789))`

Comment: Hi Gimix, sorry one last question, do we really need the primes = [] inside the class? Because when I omit this, everything still works, and it doesn't make sense to me why it is there, because it seems like we are just redefining it inside our methods?

Comment: Strictly speaking it is not needed. But defining object members as soon as possible is a good practice - it improves readability, and prevents errors... what if you call `goodNumbers` _before_ calling `primeNumber`

Comment: I see, so it is just for the reader! This makes so much more sense now. Thanks for the time to respond!

Answer (score 0):

you can add the list as a variable which you can pass data to:
e.g.

```
def goodNumbers(self,n,primes = [] ):
    newprime = ( get the next prime number )
    if not newprime in primes:
        primes.append( newprime )
    return primes

primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
goodnumbers( n, primes )
```